# Self join produces inconsistent value for last month

Tags: sql, t-sql, join

In order to display some records from the previous month in the same row, I had to join my table to itself like this:

```
SELECT 
      a.[periodOrderNum]
      ,SUM(a.AktivNy) as ActiveNew
      ,SUM(b.[AktivNy]) as ActiveNewPrevMonth
  FROM myTable a
  JOIN myTable b 
    ON a.customerSNKey = b.customerSNKey 
   AND a.periodOrderNum = b.periodOrderNum + 1
  GROUP BY a.[periodOrderNum]
```

In the above code `periodOrderNum` is an order number assigned to period. E.g if the current period is 5, then the previous period has an order number of 4.

And `customerSNKey` is customer's serial number key which I use as one of my `JOIN` conditions. The other condition (`a.periodOrderNum = b.periodOrderNum + 1`) I use to get the value of previous period. But the results are not consistent. As seen in the picture below, for order number 280, the value of `ActiveNewPrevMonth` is 20203 which is not the `ActiveNew` value of order number 279.

[image]

What am I doing wrong in my join?

Comment: It's hard to tell since all of the data is not shown.  I would run the query without the join and have "AND periodOrderNum = 280" to see what it is trying to SUM, just to make sure.  Could you add those results to your question?

Comment: Make up some data and show DDL, input, output and expected output. Read and act on [mcve]. PS What if there is no previous month's data?

Answer (score 1):

Without some sample data, I can't tell where went wrong. But either way, your query here will return wrong value anyway I believe. Say if your have multiple rows under same `periodOrderNum`, your `ActiveNew` value is pretty much guaranteed to be exaggerated. How about try to separate them into subqueries like this:

```
 SELECT a.[periodOrderNum]
 ,a.ActiveNew
 ,b.ActiveNewPrevMonth
 FROM
 (
 SELECT 
 customerSNKey, [periodOrderNum]
 ,SUM(AktivNy) as ActiveNew
 FROM myTable
 GROUP BY customerSNKey, [periodOrderNum]
 ) AS a
 INNER JOIN 
 (
 SELECT 
 customerSNKey, [periodOrderNum] + 1 as [periodOrderNum]
 ,SUM(AktivNy) as ActiveNewPrevMonth
 FROM myTable
 GROUP BY customerSNKey, [periodOrderNum] + 1
 ) AS b
 ON a.customerSNKey = b.customerSNKey
 AND a.[periodOrderNum] = b.[periodOrderNum]
```

Comment: Sorry. Have no access to the db atm. Will get back to you as soon as I can.

Comment: Hi and sorry for the long delay. Your query is giving me only 0s and 1s as `ActiveNew` and `ActiveNewPrevMonth`. I wish I could help you with some sample data but I am afraid I am not allowed to.